# How to extract bias weights in Keras sequential model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I'm running a simple feed-forward network using *Keras* . 
Having just one hidden layer I would like to make some inference regarding the relevance of each input to each output and I would like to extract the weights.

This is the model:

```
def build_model(input_dim, output_dim):
    n_output_layer_1 = 150
    n_output = output_dim
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(n_output_layer_1, input_dim=input_dim, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Dense(n_output))
```

To extract the weight I wrote:

```
for layer in model.layers:
    weights = layer.get_weights() 


weights = np.array(weights[0])     #this is hidden to output
first = model.layers[0].get_weights() #input to hidden
first = np.array(first[0])
```

Unfortunately I don't get the biases columns in the matrices, which I know Keras automatically puts in it.

**Do you know how to retrieve the biases weights?**

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`get_weights()` for a `Dense` layer returns a list of two elements, the first element contains the weights, and the second element contains the biases. So you can simply do:

```
weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
biases = model.layers[0].get_weights()[1]
```

Note that weights and biases are already numpy arrays.

Comment: sorry for bothering you, what kind of activation function does the output have in my model? Is there a default choice or is it just a weighted sum of the hidden neurons activations?

Comment: By default, keras selects 'linear' activation. Check out [Dense layer documentation](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense). Default for `activation=None`, meaning `a(x)=x`

Comment: Does each neuron have its own bias weight?

Comment: The above gives numpy arrays. If you want tensors use the following: weights = model.layers[0].weights[0]
biases = model.layers[0].weights[1]