# How to pass the weights of previous layers as input to a call function,of a custum layer, in a functional Keras Model?

Tags: python, keras, functional-programming, neural-network, tensor

For the call method of my custom layer I need the weights of some precedent layers, but I don't need to modify them only access to their value.
I have the value as suggest in [How do I get the weights of a layer in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43715047/how-do-i-get-the-weights-of-a-layer-in-keras)
but this returns weights as numpy array.
So I have cast them in Tensor (using tf.convert_to_tensor from Keras backend) but, in the moment of the creation of the model I have this error "'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'".
How can I fix this problem?
Thanks you.

Comment: Please add code, errors make no sense without it, and also describe what this layer will do using the weights

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow provides graph collections that group the variables. To access the variables that were trained you would call `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)` or its shorthand `tf.trainable_variables()` or to get all variables (including some for statistics) use `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES)` or its shorthand `tf.all_variables()`

```
tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
tvars_vals = sess.run(tvars)

for var, val in zip(tvars, tvars_vals):
    print(var.name, val)  # Prints the name of the variable alongside its value.
```

Comment: @MariaLauraBennato You're welcome. Did this solve your problem, did you test it? If yes please accept my answer with  check mark.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass this precedent layer while initializing your custom layer class.

Custom Layer:

```
class CustomLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, reference_layer):
      super(CustomLayer, self).__init__()
      self.ref_layer = reference_layer # precedent layer

    def call(self, inputs):
        weights = self.ref_layer.get_weights()
        ''' do something with these weights '''
        return something
```

Now you add this layer to your model using [Functional-API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional).

```
inp = Input(shape=(5))
dense = Dense(5)
custom_layer= CustomLayer(dense) # pass layer here

#model
x = dense(inp)
x = custom_layer(x)
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=x)
```

Here `custom_layer` can access weights of layer `dense`.