# How to get weight on each layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, keras-layer

I'm trying to get the input weight on each layer, including the lstm 1, lstm 2, and weight after the attention layer, and want to display them using a heatmap. But when I run the code, the following error appears. What happened? Because the layer exists.
Here is the code:

```
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features), return_sequences=True))
#print weights
print(model.get_layer(LSTM).get_weights()[0])
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(attention(return_sequences=False)) # receive 3D and output 2D
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit network
model.fit(trainX, trainy, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
# evaluate model
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(testX, testy, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
```

Attention layer:

```
class attention(Layer):
def __init__(self, return_sequences=True):
    self.return_sequences = return_sequences
    super(attention,self).__init__()
def build(self, input_shape):
    self.W=self.add_weight(name="att_weight", shape=(input_shape[-1],1),
                           initializer="normal")
    self.b=self.add_weight(name="att_bias", shape=(input_shape[1],1),
                           initializer="zeros")
    super(attention,self).build(input_shape)
def call(self, x):
    e = K.tanh(K.dot(x,self.W)+self.b)
    a = K.softmax(e, axis=1)
    output = x*a
    if self.return_sequences:
        return output
    return K.sum(output, axis=1)
```

And this is the error that appears:

```
ValueError: No such layer: <class 'keras.layers.recurrent_v2.LSTM'>. Existing layers are [<keras.layers.recurrent_v2.LSTM object at 0x7f7b5c215910>].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get certain layer weights using `model.layers` after defining your whole model:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class attention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, return_sequences=True):
      self.return_sequences = return_sequences
      super(attention,self).__init__()
  def build(self, input_shape):
      self.W=self.add_weight(name="att_weight", shape=(input_shape[-1],1),
                            initializer="normal")
      self.b=self.add_weight(name="att_bias", shape=(input_shape[1],1),
                            initializer="zeros")
      super(attention,self).build(input_shape)
  def call(self, x):
      e = tf.keras.backend.tanh(tf.keras.backend.dot(x,self.W)+self.b)
      a = tf.keras.backend.softmax(e, axis=1)
      output = x*a
      if self.return_sequences:
          return output
      return tf.keras.backend.sum(output, axis=1)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, input_shape=(5,10), return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1))
model.add(attention(return_sequences=False)) # receive 3D and output 2D
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

trainx = tf.random.normal((25, 5, 10))
trainy = tf.random.uniform((25, 3), maxval=3)
model.fit(trainx, trainy, epochs=5, batch_size=4)


lstm1_weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
lstm2_weights = model.layers[1].get_weights()[0]
attention_weights = model.layers[3].get_weights()[0]

heat_map = sb.heatmap(lstm1_weights)
plt.show()
```

```
Model: "sequential_16"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 lstm_24 (LSTM)              (None, 5, 32)             5504      
                                                                 
 lstm_25 (LSTM)              (None, 5, 32)             8320      
                                                                 
 dropout_12 (Dropout)        (None, 5, 32)             0         
                                                                 
 attention_12 (attention)    (None, 32)                37        
                                                                 
 dense_12 (Dense)            (None, 3)                 99        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 13,960
Trainable params: 13,960
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/5
7/7 [==============================] - 4s 10ms/step - loss: 5.5033 - accuracy: 0.4400
Epoch 2/5
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: 5.4899 - accuracy: 0.5200
Epoch 3/5
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 5.4771 - accuracy: 0.4800
Epoch 4/5
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 5.4701 - accuracy: 0.5200
Epoch 5/5
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: 5.4569 - accuracy: 0.5200
```

[image]

If you want to see how the weights of your layers change during training, you should define a callback as shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43715047/how-do-i-get-the-weights-of-a-layer-in-keras).

Comment: Woaaa thank you so much for your help. I'm having a hard time finding the cause and solving it. I will try like your suggestion. Once again, thank you so much

Comment: I want to ask again, may I know what each label indicates?

Comment: In the example I posted the labels do not mean anything special.. Just three different classes.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I hope I can ask again if I get into trouble.