# How to get weight in each layer and epoch then save in file

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, attention-model

I am trying to get the weight value in each layer in each epoch and then save it in a file.
I am trying to implement the code proposed by Eric M on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43715047/how-do-i-get-the-weights-of-a-layer-in-keras). But while still trying to get the weight value, I get an error like this:

```
<ipython-input-15-81ab617ec631> in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
w = self.model.layers[layer_i].get_weights()[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What happened? Because layer_i only gets the number of layers I use. Is it because of the attention layer that I use? I also can't save it to a file because I don't know what the code produces.

Here's the callbacks and model that I use:

```
class GetWeights(keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def __init__(self):
    super(GetWeights, self).__init__()
    self.weight_dict = {}
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    for layer_i in range(len(self.model.layers)):
      w = self.model.layers[layer_i].get_weights()[0]
      b = self.model.layers[layer_i].get_weights()[1]
      heat_map = sb.heatmap(w)
      pyplot.show()
      print('Layer %s has weights of shape %s and biases of shape %s' %(layer_i, np.shape(w), np.shape(b)))
      if epoch == 0:
        # create array to hold weights and biases
        self.weight_dict['w_'+str(layer_i+1)] = w
        self.weight_dict['b_'+str(layer_i+1)] = b
      else:
        # append new weights to previously-created weights array
        self.weight_dict['w_'+str(layer_i+1)] = np.dstack(
            (self.weight_dict['w_'+str(layer_i+1)], w))
        # append new weights to previously-created weights array
        self.weight_dict['b_'+str(layer_i+1)] = np.dstack(
            (self.weight_dict['b_'+str(layer_i+1)], b))

gw = GetWeights()
model = Sequential() 
model.add(LSTM(hidden_units_masukan, input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(hidden_units_masukan, input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(dropout_masukan))
model.add(attention(return_sequences=False)) # receive 3D and output 2D
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation=activation_masukan))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer_masukan, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(trainX, trainy, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size_masukan, verbose=verbose, callbacks=[gw],)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to extract the weights and biases from each layer in your model, but a `Dropout` layer does not have any weights. This is why you get this error message. You need to exclude this layer. Here is a working example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class attention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, return_sequences=True):
      self.return_sequences = return_sequences
      super(attention,self).__init__()
  def build(self, input_shape):
      self.W=self.add_weight(name="att_weight", shape=(input_shape[-1],1),
                            initializer="normal")
      self.b=self.add_weight(name="att_bias", shape=(input_shape[1],1),
                            initializer="zeros")
      super(attention,self).build(input_shape)
  def call(self, x):
      e = tf.keras.backend.tanh(tf.keras.backend.dot(x,self.W)+self.b)
      a = tf.keras.backend.softmax(e, axis=1)
      output = x*a
      if self.return_sequences:
          return output
      return tf.keras.backend.sum(output, axis=1)

class GetWeights(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def __init__(self):
    super(GetWeights, self).__init__()
    self.weight_dict = {}
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    drop_out_index = 2
    for i, layer in enumerate(self.model.layers):
      if drop_out_index != i:
        w = layer.get_weights()[0]
        b = layer.get_weights()[1]
        heat_map = sb.heatmap(w)
        plt.show()
        print('Layer %s has weights of shape %s and biases of shape %s' %(i, np.shape(w), np.shape(b)))
        if epoch == 0:
          # create array to hold weights and biases
          self.weight_dict['w_'+str(i+1)] = w
          self.weight_dict['b_'+str(i+1)] = b
        else:
          # append new weights to previously-created weights array
          self.weight_dict['w_'+str(i+1)] = np.dstack(
              (self.weight_dict['w_'+str(i+1)], w))
          # append new weights to previously-created weights array
          self.weight_dict['b_'+str(i+1)] = np.dstack(
              (self.weight_dict['b_'+str(i+1)], b))

gw = GetWeights()
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, input_shape=(5,10), return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1))
model.add(attention(return_sequences=False)) # receive 3D and output 2D
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

trainx = tf.random.normal((25, 5, 10))
trainy = tf.random.uniform((25, 3), maxval=3)
model.fit(trainx, trainy, epochs=1, batch_size=4, callbacks=[gw])
```

```
Model: "sequential_11"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 lstm_22 (LSTM)              (None, 5, 32)             5504      
                                                                 
 lstm_23 (LSTM)              (None, 5, 32)             8320      
                                                                 
 dropout_11 (Dropout)        (None, 5, 32)             0         
                                                                 
 attention_11 (attention)    (None, 32)                37        
                                                                 
 dense_11 (Dense)            (None, 3)                 99        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 13,960
Trainable params: 13,960
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
7/7 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 4.4367 - accuracy: 0.3200     

Layer 0 has weights of shape (10, 128) and biases of shape (32, 128)

Layer 1 has weights of shape (32, 128) and biases of shape (32, 128)

Layer 3 has weights of shape (32, 1) and biases of shape (5, 1)

Layer 4 has weights of shape (32, 3) and biases of shape (3,)
7/7 [==============================] - 5s 265ms/step - loss: 4.4367 - accuracy: 0.3200
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f3914737b10>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining and including the code. I just learned from you that dropout only disables hidden neurons and has no weight and bias.
May i ask again? When I print it with heatmap, I get the same image every epoch. How did it happen? While the seaborn code is in each epoch and should produce a different hetmap.

Comment: You get the same image of what ? Look at your model summary, the `Dropout` layer does not have any trainable parameters.

Comment: I mean, when I try to run the program, the output is like this: [Link](https://imgur.com/a/jxJl3E5) . Always the same in every epoch, while the accuracy obtained is different every epoch. I am very confused about it, is there a wrong code or is my setting wrong.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. The changes in the weights are just too small to see them in the heatmaps.. You will have to tune the parameters of the heatmap like `vmin` and `vmax`. This is, however, beyond the scope of your original question. So if you need help, ask a new question.

Comment: aaa so it might happen due to a very small changes, I just got it. Sorry because I'm new to deep learning and python. I am very grateful for your help and explanation. Thank you so much.