# How can I plot the gradient while training my RNN (LSTM)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

I am new to machine learning and tried to follow the tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/music_generation. I noticed that sometimes the results become very bad, depending on the data input. After talking about it, I now suspect that this might be a case of gradient vanishing/exploding.

In order to check this hypothesis, I would like to plot the gradient. However, everything I found online didn't seem to work or I was unable to make it work with my limited knowledge on that matter.

## What I have tried

1. [How to visualize RNN/LSTM gradients in Keras/TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59017288/how-to-visualize-rnn-lstm-gradients-in-keras-tensorflow). I did try rolling TensorFlow back to 2.9, but the input wasn't compatible with my input and I didn't see an easy way to fix it. Just splitting the label and data again, didn't seem to work.
2. I tried taking a look at the weights directly instead of the gradients, but just got more confused, because the heatmap is a bit hard to get - at least for me: [How to get weight in each layer and epoch then save in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70133704/how-to-get-weight-in-each-layer-and-epoch-then-save-in-file#answer-70136833)