# How to use tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss with Tensorflow Keras?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I've been looking around a way to use sampled softmax `tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss()` for one of my models. I couldn't find any post that could help me on how to implement it.

If anyone has implemented it with Keras architecture, would you please let me know how to use it with keras?

Right now for other losses I could just use,

```
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy())
```

But I can't use tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss in that manner `model.compile(loss=tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss())`?

I've tried using `model.compile(loss=tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss())` but it returned error which I think it's correct because it takes in weights and biases from last layer to calculate loss which I'm not sure how to implement in keras.

Comment: have you  tried using `layer.get_weights()` to get the weights of the last layer

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat I don't know how to use it. I've checked all other such questions on SO none of those worked for me. Also tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss should only used for trainign and for eval we have to let model use normal entropy loss. So I don't know how to do that. I was hoping someone experienced might have implemented it.

Comment: [check out this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42411891/how-to-extract-bias-weights-in-keras-sequential-model/42412124)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sampled_softmax_loss() computes and returns the sampled softmax training loss.

This is a faster way to train a softmax classifier over a huge number of classes.

This operation is for training only. It is generally an underestimate of the full softmax loss.

A common use case is to use this method for training, and calculate the full softmax loss for evaluation or inference. In this case, you must set `partition_strategy="div"` for the two losses to be consistent, as in the following example:

```
if mode == "train":
  loss = tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(
      weights=weights,
      biases=biases,
      labels=labels,
      inputs=inputs,
      ...,
      partition_strategy="div")
elif mode == "eval":
  logits = tf.matmul(inputs, tf.transpose(weights))
  logits = tf.nn.bias_add(logits, biases)
  labels_one_hot = tf.one_hot(labels, n_classes)
  loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
      labels=labels_one_hot,
      logits=logits)
```

Where regular loss functions like CategoricalCrossentropy() uses it's default values, even if you don't pass any arguments it will calculate the loss based on its default values.

The key point for sampled_softmax_loss is to pass right shape of `weight`, `bias`, `input` and `label`.
 The shape of weight passed to sampled_softmax is not the the same with the general situation.
 For example, `logits = xw + b`, call sampled_softmax like this:

`sampled_softmax(weight=tf.transpose(w), bias=b, inputs=x)`,
NOT `sampled_softmax(weight=w, bias=b, inputs=logits)`!!

Besides, label is not one-hot representation. if your labels are one-hot represented, pass `labels=tf.reshape(tf.argmax(labels_one_hot, 1), [-1,1])`

Comment: @user_12 - If you think I have answered your question, please accept and upvote, Thank You.