# Why do I get 6 parameters in Keras in simple 2 output 2 input network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am learning about neural networks in keras. I specified a simple model on made up data.

```
model=tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, input_dim=2))
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

I have two attributes to predict two values.

Here is where I initialize my data:

```
x=[]
y=[]
for x1 in range (6):
    x2=int(random.random()*10)
    x.append([x1,x2])
    y.append([2*x1+x2**2-2, x1*x2])
xs = np.array(x, dtype=float)
xs=xs.reshape(6,2)
ys = np.array(y, dtype=float)
ys=ys.reshape(6,2)
model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=500)
```

Mind you, I use the data solely for the purpose of learning. After I attempted to observe the model. I run `model.summary()` and `model.get_weights()`.

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 2)                 6         
=================================================================
Total params: 6
Trainable params: 6
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
model weights  [array([[0.5137405, 5.477211 ],
       [8.750836 , 1.6910588]], dtype=float32), array([-5.701193, -7.874653], dtype=float32)]
```

I don't understand why are there 6 params and six weights. From my understanding there should be two going from each input, or should I have somewhere specifically defined the output layer?

Comment: Aren't these values just the [biases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053170/how-can-i-get-biases-from-a-trained-model-in-keras)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the number of parameters for convolutional neural network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42786717/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-parameters-for-convolutional-neural-network)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model architecture you have defined is pictorially shown below

[image]

You have one dense layer with two neurons.  Why two neurons ? because the first parameter to `Dense` is `units` which denotes the number of neurons. Each neuron does linear operation of `X.W + b` and then applies activation function over it. The learnable parameters in a nuerons are `W` and `b`.

Since the size of `X` is 2 (2 features) so size of `W`(=2) +`b` = 3. So each neuron in this case will have 3 parameters and 2 such will have 6 parameters.

Comment: By dense layer you are reffering to a node in the neural network?

Answer (score 1):

You have a single output layer with two neurons, each of these neurons must have two weights (since the inputs are of dimension 2) and another weight called "bias". So each neuron has 3 weights.

In summary, you have 2 neurons and each one has 3 weights or trainable parameters, so in total there are 6 trainable parameters in your network.