# How can I save the biases of my trained neural network in keras?

Tags: keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am building a CNN using keras and I know that I can save the weights using `model.save_weights()` but how can I save the biases of the neural network? Am I missing something or is it that Keras just doesn't provide biases?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053170/how-can-i-get-biases-from-a-trained-model-in-keras

Comment: biases are also weights, so the biases are also saved in that function