# How to chang the output of the concrete function in Tensorflow 2.x?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

I have trained a TensorFlow model and saved it to a local disk. when I loaded it and do inference, how can I get the output of the intermediate layer?

I use the example in the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/advanced) as a demo.

The model is:

```py
class MyModel(Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')
    self.flatten = Flatten()
    self.d1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')
    self.d2 = Dense(10)

  def call(self, x):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.flatten(x)
    x = self.d1(x)
    return self.d2(x)

# Create an instance of the model
model = MyModel()
```

I save the model to local and load it in another place.

```py
# save model to local
tf.saved_model.save(model, export_dir="./saved_model")

# load model from local
loaded = tf.saved_model.load("./saved_model")
concrete_fun = loaded.signatures["serving_default"]
# do reference
out = concrete_fun(tf.zeros((2, 28, 28, 1)))
out["output_1"].shape
```

As I know, the [concrete function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/types/experimental/ConcreteFunction) is unique to the `input` and `output`.

How can I get the `output`, `weights` and `bias` of intermediate layers, for example `self.conv1`?

Comment: Before saving the model to local, I did the training process. The code can be reproduced by running the [demo](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/advanced).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try running:

```
print([var for var in concrete_fun.trainable_variables])
```

to get your each layer's weights and biases. To access the graph of your model, you can run `concrete_fun.graph`. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_operations) for more details.

To access the output of intermediate layers, it would be easiest to save the model like this:

```
model.save('your_model', save_format='tf')
```

and then load it:

```
model.save('your_model', save_format='tf')
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('your_model')
conv_layer = model.get_layer(index=0)
print(conv_layer(tf.random.normal((1, 28, 28, 1))).shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access any layer in your model with the `.get_layer()` method ([Model class](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#get_layer)). You just need the name of the layer:

```
conv1_layer = model.get_layer("name_of_the_layer")
```

From this you can access the weights ([Layer class](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#get_weights) ):

```
conv1_layer.get_weights()
```

the output:

```
conv1_layer.output
```

and the bias (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42053507/13469674):

```
conv1_layer.get_weights()[1]
```